# Sum of a property inside multiple, similar arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, sum

We have arrays of hashes, each of which has a `value` property and a `timeframe` property:

```
result1 = [
  {"value"=>1, "timeframe"=>{"start"=>"2016-05-27T00:00:00.000Z", "end"=>"2016-05-28T00:00:00.000Z"}},
  {"value"=>1, "timeframe"=>{"start"=>"2016-05-28T00:00:00.000Z", "end"=>"2016-05-29T00:00:00.000Z"}},
  {"value"=>1, "timeframe"=>{"start"=>"2016-05-29T00:00:00.000Z", "end"=>"2016-05-30T00:00:00.000Z"}}
]

result2 = [
  {"value"=>2, "timeframe"=>{"start"=>"2016-05-27T00:00:00.000Z", "end"=>"2016-05-28T00:00:00.000Z"}},
  {"value"=>2, "timeframe"=>{"start"=>"2016-05-28T00:00:00.000Z", "end"=>"2016-05-29T00:00:00.000Z"}},
  {"value"=>2, "timeframe"=>{"start"=>"2016-05-29T00:00:00.000Z", "end"=>"2016-05-30T00:00:00.000Z"}}
]
```

We need to build an array that will be the sum of the `value` property of each item in the matching position, so something like:

```
[3, 3, 3]
```

EDIT: Edited the question to be simpler and hopefully less confusing.  Sorry to the guys who tried to help with this, really appreciate your input

Comment: How are the `"start"` and `"end"` values related to the `:date` value? Not clear.

Comment: I agree with sawa that is was not clear that you wanted only the start date of each timeframe in the resulting hashes. My answer probably was wrong because of this. And you did not even comment on it. I am disappointed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[result1, result2].reduce(:+)
                  .map { |e| [e['timeframe']['start'], e['value']] }
                  .each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |(d, v), memo| memo[d] += v }  
#⇒ {
#     "2016-05-27T00:00:00.000Z" => 3,
#     "2016-05-28T00:00:00.000Z" => 3,
#     "2016-05-29T00:00:00.000Z" => 3
# }
```

To get only values out from hash, use [`Hash#values`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html#method-i-values).

Comment: Is reduce different than `(result1 + result2)`?

Comment: Nope, they are the same. I changed to `reduce(:+)` to clarify the intent. I used `reduce` because there might be an array of `result` arrays and in this case adding them up with inline `+` is tricky.

Comment: Great, what the pipe doing the same thing? I've never seen it

Comment: [`Array#|`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-7C) adds up arrays’ elements, removing duplicates. Since your elements are hashes, that was safe to use it, but `+` here is more semantically correct.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you first construct a hash with dates as keys and the totals as values. This is a non-trivial hash construction, so I suggest doing it incrementally with `each` instead of with a `map`.

```
totals_per_date = Hash.new(0)
results = [*result1, *result2]
results.each do |record|
  first_day = record["timeframe"]["start"].to_date
  last_day  = record["timeframe"]["end"].to_date
  (first_day..last_day).each do |day|
    totals_per_date[day] += record["value"]
  end
end
```

Transforming that to the specified target hash is a good use case for `map`:

```
graph_data = totals_per_date.map{ |day, total| {date: day, total: total} }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your might consider making your return value a hash, rather than an array of hashes:

```
(result1+result2).each_with_object({}) { |g,h|
  h.update(g["timeframe"]["start"]=>g["value"]) { |_,o,n| o+n } }
  #=> {"2016-05-27T00:00:00.000Z"=>3,
  #    "2016-05-28T00:00:00.000Z"=>3,
  #    "2016-05-29T00:00:00.000Z"=>3}
```

This uses the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `Hash#merge!`) that employs a block (`{ |k,o,n| o+n }`) to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. See the doc for the meanings of the three block variables. The common key, `k`, is not used in the block calculation, so, as is customary, I've changed it to `_`.

If, as stated, you want to return an array of hashes, there is one more step:

```
(result1+result2).each_with_object({}) { |g,h|
  h.update(g["timeframe"]["start"]=>g["value"]) { |_,o,n| o+n } }.
  map { |k,v| { date: k, value: v } }
  #=> [{:date=>"2016-05-27T00:00:00.000Z", :value=>3},
  #    {:date=>"2016-05-28T00:00:00.000Z", :value=>3},
  #    {:date=>"2016-05-29T00:00:00.000Z", :value=>3}]
```